# Проверка состояния сервиса и засыпание цикла если сервис недоступен BASH

Tags: bash

Есть скрипт

```
#!/bin/bash
start=$(date +%s.%N)            # начинаем считать время работы скрипта
pause=10                # пауза между звонками чтобы не нагружать asterisk
count_lines_sip=6           # количество линий в sip
# spooldir=/var/spool/asterisk
# diallist=/etc/asterisk/script/zvonar/diallist.txt
# lock=/media/autodialer/zvonar.lock
spooldir=/media/sysadmin2/Data/zvonar
diallist=/media/sysadmin2/Data/zvonar/diallist.txt
lock=/media/sysadmin2/Data/zvonar/zvonar.lock
# COMMAND=`/bin/systemctl status asterisk | grep Active | sed -r 's/.*\((.*)\).*/\1/'`

touch $lock             # сделаем файл защиты

echo `date`": Набор номеров с 5-и секундной паузой"

while read number; do
    sleep 5
    cat <<EOF > $spooldir/tmp/$number
Channel: Local/8$number@zvonar-dialer
MaxRetries: 1
RetryTime: 5
WaitTime: 25
Context: zvonar-informer
Extension: 999
Callerid: 999
Account: autodialer
Priority: 1
EOF
    
    chmod 777 $spooldir/tmp/$number
    # chown asterisk:asterisk $spooldir/tmp/$number
    mv $spooldir/tmp/$number $spooldir/outgoing
    
    echo "$number"
    number=`expr $number + 1`

    while [ "$?" -eq "0" ]; do # проверяем значение последней команды
        
        count_files (){
            count_f=`ls $spooldir/outgoing | wc -l`

            if [ "$count_f" -eq "$count_lines_sip" ]; then
                sleep $pause
                return 0
            else
                return 1
            fi
        }

        count_files # запускаем функцию подсчета количества файлов в директории. Если файлов в директории равно количеству линий то засыпаем, иначе дописываем количество до 6-и
    done
done < "$diallist"          # конец цикла

echo "Done"

rm -f $lock             # удаляем файл защиты
# rm -f $diallist               # удалим файл с номерами телефонов, чтобы не было ложных срабатываний

end=$(date +%s.%N)          # конец счета времени работы скрипта
result=`echo "$end-$start" | bc -l | xargs printf "%.2f"`   # получаем затраченное время и округляем результат до 2-х знаков после запятой
echo "Время работы: $result секунд"
exit 0                  # выходим
```

Я написал еще один скрипт который проверяет состояние сервиса

```
#!/bin/bash
COMMAND=`/bin/systemctl status asterisk | grep Active | sed -r 's/.*\((.*)\).*/\1/'`

if [[ "$COMMAND" -eq 'dead' ]]; then
    echo "Не работает"
elif [[ "$COMMAND" -eq 'running' ]]; then
    echo "Работает"
fi
```

Хотел их объединить в один но почему-то при запуске скрипт смотрит состояние и при изменении состояния сервиса, скрипт не отслеживает это.

Я делал вот так в функции count_files

```
count_files (){
            count_f=`ls $spooldir/outgoing | wc -l`

            if [[ "$COMMAND" -eq 'dead' ]]; then
                echo "Не работает"
                sleep $pause
            elif [[ "$COMMAND" -eq 'running' ]]; then
                echo "Работает"
                if [ "$count_f" -eq "$count_lines_sip" ]; then
                    sleep $pause
                    return 0
                else
                    return 1
                fi
            fi

            
        }
```

Comment: запустите debug с помощью `bash -x ./script.sh` и попробуйте отследить что не так

Comment: Я так понимаю, ты хочешь придумать `систему управления конфигурацией`?

Answer (score -1):

Решил проблему вот так. Но считаю что это костыль

```
while [ "$?" -eq "0" ]; do # проверяем значение последней команды

        COMMAND=`/bin/systemctl status nginx | grep Active | sed -r 's/.*\((.*)\).*/\1/'`

        if [ "$COMMAND" == "dead" ]; then
            echo "Сервис остановлен"
            sleep $pause
        else
            
            count_files (){
                count_f=`ls $spooldir/outgoing | wc -l`

                if [ "$count_f" -eq "$count_lines_sip" ]; then
                    sleep $pause
                    return 0
                else
                    return 1
                fi
            }

            count_files # запускаем функцию подсчета количества файлов в директории. Если файлов в директории равно количеству линий то засыпаем, иначе дописываем количество до 6-и
        fi      
    done
```

Comment: `systemctl is-active --quiet servicename && { блок если сервис работает; } || { блок если сервис НЕ работает; }`